# Parent activity loses CallingActivity after child finish()-es

Tags: android

I'm having trouble with activities and their calling parent. My application gets launch by an external application as a "plugin". The basic layout looks like this.

`External App > MyActivity_A > MyActivity_B`

I launch `MyActivity_B` from `MyActivity_A` as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity_B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
intent.putExtra(AppIntents.AMOUNT, due);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

`MyActivityB` has the option to be dismissed which I dismiss it as follows:

```
public void onBack(View view) {
    finish();
}
```

`MyActivity_A` has the following callback:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String activity = this.getCallingActivity() != null ? this.getCallingActivity().getClassName() : "Null";
    Utils.log(activity);
}
```

When `MyActivity_A` is launched from the `External App` the log prints out the app's package name. However when `onResume` is called after `MyActivity_B` has been dismissed, the log prints `Null`. I'm not sure why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: you are not starting MyActivity_A from MyActivity_B, you are just finishing MyActivity_B, so there is no activity calling MyActivity_A that's why the log prints null

Comment: Read more about **Tasks and Back Stack** [https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html ]

Answer (score 0):

when you start `MyActivity_B` from `MyActivity_A` you have to finish `MyActivity_A` and when you dismiss `MyActivity_B` you have to start `MyActivity_A` so you can get name of callingActivity..

otherwise you have to manage by `saveInstance` when you get it at first time and later you can use that instance

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to transfer the *result* from `ActivityB` to the `ExternalApp` without *proxying* it through `ActivityA` first (since you are using [`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT)).

If this is the case, try calling [`finish()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()) inside `ActivityA` when you launch `ActivityB` and then call [`setResult(RESULT_CANCELED)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int)) inside `onBack(...)` in `ActivityB`

Finally, to receive the *response* in the `ExternalApp`, you need to launch the *"plugin"* with [`startActivityForResult(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))

Comment: that's basically what I'm trying to do. However if I finish() activity A before launching B the user can just tap back will return back to the external app instead of ActivityA

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [Official Document for this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity())

It has clearly mentioned

**Note: if the calling activity is not expecting a result (that is it did not use the startActivityForResult(Intent, int) form that includes a request code), then the calling package will be null.**

In your case, you are calling 
MyActivity_A > MyActivity_B and not requesting any result

**this.startActivity(intent);**

if You are expecting any result from calling activity "MyActivity_B" then and only then it will give the name of calling activity

your code supposed to be like this,

```
//From MyActivity_A
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity_B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
intent.putExtra(AppIntents.AMOUNT, due);
this.startActivityForResult(intent,10);

//From MyActivity_B
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("test_string_data","https://www.google.com/")
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();

//or
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
finish();
```

Hope it will help you.